# NuxtプロジェクトでのJest スナップショットテストエラー

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, jestjs

初めて質問します！
他人が作成したNuxtプロジェクトを引き継いで開発をしている新米エンジニアです。
Jestのスナップショットテストでエラーが出て、どうしようもないのでどなたかヒントをお与えください....!!

## 困っていること

コマンドラインにて`$jest --coverage`ののち、テスト結果でエラーが出ています。
上位コマンド実行後の出力結果のうち、エラーに関係がある最後の部分のみ書きます。

#### コマンドライン

```
Summary of all failing tests
 FAIL  spec/components/ActivityWritingModal.spec.js
  ● components/ActivityWritingModal.vue › スナップショット

    expect(received).toMatchSnapshot()

    Snapshot name: `components/ActivityWritingModal.vue スナップショット 1`

    - Snapshot
    + Received

    @@ -58,11 +58,21 @@
                        hint="カレンダーアイコンをクリックすると、今日の日付が入ります"
                        label="タイトル"
                        loaderheight="2"
                        messages=""
                        required=""
    -                   rules="v => !!v || 'タイトルは必須です'"
    +                   rules="v => {
    +         /* istanbul ignore next */
    +         cov_2l6sjua4gi.f[2]++;
    +         cov_2l6sjua4gi.s[12]++;
    +         return (
    +           /* istanbul ignore next */
    +           (cov_2l6sjua4gi.b[3][0]++, !!v) ||
    +           /* istanbul ignore next */
    +           (cov_2l6sjua4gi.b[3][1]++, 'タイトルは必須です')
    +         );
    +       }"
                        successmessages=""
                        type="text"
                        value=""
                      />
                    </v-flex-stub>

      49 |     })
      50 | 
    > 51 |     expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot()
         |                             ^
      52 |   })
      53 | 
      54 |   it('mountされる', () => {

      at Object.toMatchSnapshot (spec/components/ActivityWritingModal.spec.js:51:29)


Snapshot Summary
 › 1 snapshot failed from 1 test suite. Inspect your code changes or run `yarn test -u` to update them.

Test Suites: 1 failed, 23 passed, 24 total
Tests:       1 failed, 63 passed, 64 total
Snapshots:   1 failed, 14 passed, 15 total
Time:        8.269s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
husky > pre-push hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```